# Clicking on radio button does not issue the alert using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

On clicking the radio button nothing happens, why?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">          
            $("input[name='check1']",$('#Search_By')).change(function()
            {
                alert('yo');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="well">
        <form action="/abc/readservlet" method="post">
            <div class="well" id="Search_By">
                <h3><b/>Search BY</h3>
                <input type="Radio" name="check1" value="Search BY Key"> Key<br/><br/>
                <input type="Radio" name="check1" value="Search By Tablename"> Tab_name         
                <br/>
            </div>
```

On clicking radio button nothing happens...

Answer (score 5):

If your `<script>` tag has a `src` attribute, [its contents will be ignored](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html#script-constraints), so your code isn't going to actually run at all.

You need to put your code into a separate script tag and run the code when the document is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Search_By input[name='check1']")).change(function() {
            alert('yo');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or put both of those script tags at the very bottom of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @gusc: Do you have a `jquery.js` file? Is your browser actually loading it? What does your JS console say?

Comment: I did this <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>

Comment: @gusc: Look at your JS console.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code to create the onchange handler should be as follows. Try it out.

```
...
$("#Search_By input[name='check1']").change(
  function()
  {
    alert('yo');
});
...
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?!

Comment: his question was why it was not working.. the problem was here 
 `$("input[name='check1']",$('#Search_By')).change(`
so fixed it

Comment: OK, please don't just dump code as an answer. Explain the issue/problem.

Comment: @GokulKav: The context argument to the jQuery constructor can be a jQuery object. OP's original code worked: http://jsfiddle.net/q5C8e/

Comment: @blender I see. the JS was written inside jquery src tag hence no run.

Comment: @gusc refer to blender's fiddle, you cannot have JS inside a scrip tag when u specified a src to it.

Comment: @LeeTaylor yep will do